# alert msg once, 5 seconds after the page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the below with pure JavaScript if it is possible (or jQuery)

1. the page is fully loaded.
2. wait 5 seconds.
3. alert('msg') once with no setInterval loops.

Comment: The downvotes are a result of lack of research effort  as this shouldn't be hard to research yourself and at least come up with a code attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `setTimeout`:

```
document.onload = setTimeout(function () { alert('msg'); }, 5000);
```

Comment: won't this execute setTimeout immediately and then use the return value of setTimeout when the document is loaded (in this case) do nothing with it? should it be `document.onload = function(){setTimeout(function () { alert('msg'); }, 5000);};`?

Comment: Yes, it executes `setTimeout` immediately, but the callback function doesn't execute for 5 seconds. Are you wanting to keep the return value somewhere?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but the OP said show the alert 5 secs after the document has loaded. I understand that this will show the alert after 5 secs of the browser coming across the document.onload expression not 5 secs after the document has loaded.

Comment: it works with `alert('msg');` but doesnt work with my function that write to iframe `iframe.write('msg');` why? :(

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working without seeing exactly what you want to do. You should [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include all of the code -- HTML and JavaScript -- for your exact problem. Probably, you need to do something like `iframe.onload` instead of `document.onload`.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert('msg');
    }, 
    5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`. I kept the answer as verbose as the question.

Comment: to execute after page is fully loaded including images use `$(window).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("msg");}, 5000)
})
```

do not forget put jquery reference to your html header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```